# How can I configure multiple Logger in YAML File

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, yaml, log4j2

I am unable to configure multiple loggers in my YAML file. The last logger is overriding the previous loggers.

Here is my code

```
Loggers:
      Logger:
        - name: com.example
          additivity: false
          level: info
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: RollingFileAppender_Normal
              level: info

        - name: com.example
          additivity: false
          level: info
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: RollingFileAppender_JSON
              level: info
```

All logs are getting generated in RollingFileAppender_JSON appender.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.

There are 2 solution I found to above problem.

1)

```
Loggers:
      Logger:
        - name: com.example
          additivity: false
          level: info
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: RollingFileAppender_Normal
            - ref: RollingFileAppender_JSON
            - level: info
```

2) By keeping 'additivity: false' only in the first logger

```
Loggers:
      Logger:
        - name: com.example
          level: info
          additivity: false
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: RollingFileAppender_Normal
              level: info

        - name: com.example
          level: info
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: RollingFileAppender_JSON
              level: info
```